# What is the correct syntax for using Publishers.debounce() in Swift Combine?

Tags: swift, swift5, combine

In Apple's 2019 WWDC video `Swift Combine in Practice`, they demonstrate using a `debounce` publisher to slow down the rate of messages.

```
return $username
  .debounce(for: 0.5, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
  .removeDuplicates()
  .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

However, anytime I attempt to use it in a similar fashion, I get the following error:

> Cannot invoke 'debounce' with an argument list of type '(for: Double, scheduler: RunLoop)'

The `debounce()` signature is:

```
public func debounce<S>(for dueTime: S.SchedulerTimeType.Stride, 
                          scheduler: S,
                            options: S.SchedulerOptions? = nil) -> 
                                    Publishers.Debounce<Self, S> where S : Scheduler
```

`SchedulerTimeType.Stride` appears to be initializable with a numeric but it's not working for me or my inexperience with Swift Generics is on display.

What is the correct way to call this?

**Edit**

Duplicate of [this question...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56564967)

Searching for generic words like "Combine" is, for now, rather challenging...

*macOS 10.15, Xcode 11*

Comment: Also reported here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56564967/1187415. – Apparently that is not yet implemented in the current beta release.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The [documented](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/receiving_and_handling_events_with_combine#3330061) `debounce<S>` operator accepts type `S.SchedulerTimeType.Stride` which looks something like this:

```
let sub = NotificationCenter.default
    .publisher(for: NSControl.textDidChangeNotification, object: filterField)
    .debounce(for: .milliseconds(500), scheduler: RunLoop.main)
    .subscribe(on: RunLoop.main)
    .assign(to:\MyViewModel.filterString, on: myViewModel)
```

Comment: Thank you. I think the original issue was that Xcode 11 beta 1 did not support the `scheduler` argument. In the release notes for beta 2, it is now listed as being supported. The original error was about the invalid argument to `scheduler`, not the interval but it wasn't clear to me at the time.

Comment: plus most of the code onscreen at WWDC doesn't actually compile - they tend to take a lot of creative liberty when making slides.